# Array of numbers not assignable to array of strings typescript angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm new with typescript and angular 2 and I didn't know how to solve it.

I have an array of week days and an array of seven numbers, or 0 or 1. 
Each '1' correspond to a week day, so Monday would be 1000000, Tuesday would be 0100000, Wednesday 0010000 and so on.

How can I say in a function that the first object of WeekDays array has to match the first object of the Frequency array and so on? I want to display the correct name, so if the number I give to it is 1000000 I have to display 'Monday', if the number is 0010100 I've to display 'Wednesday and Friday'.

If I simply equate the two arrays it gives me "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'", and I cannot change the Frequency array because it arrives from a server.

@Component

```
weekDays: string[] = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

frequencyArray: number[] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; //or whatever you want

loadFrequencyLabel() {
  var binary = this.prescription.frequencyArray;
  var label: string;

  for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) { 
     binary[i] = this.weekDays[i];
     return label;
  }
}
```

Template

```
<p class="frequency-label">{{loadFrequencyLabel()}}</p>
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: Cant understand your logic, as in why u wrote return inside for loop.
Any ways change `frequencyArray: number[] = [1000000]` to  `frequencyArray:any[] = [1000000]`

Comment: I can't because that array of numbers arrives from a server, now I wrote there to let understand you. Anyway I edited the question, the array is [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] @ParthGhiya

Comment: Anyway I wrote return inside for loop because it must return the name of the Day for each 1 he find.

Comment: then binary will always be 1, because in iteration of first loop it will return & End

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `frequencyArray`, which you've set to a `number[]`, and `weekDays`, which you set to a `string[]`. That's fine. I think what you want to do is make a third `string[]` which contains the weekdays where the `frequencyArray` contains a 1:

```js
let weekDays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

let frequencyArray = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];

let days = frequencyArray.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  if (curr === 1) acc.push(weekDays[index]);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(days.join(' and '));
```

I've simplified the code somewhat to make it more understandable. The [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) function essentially boils an array down to a single value, or in this case, to another array. The first argument is a function that is called for each element in the array (in the parameter I've named `curr`). It also keeps track of the result in an "accumulator" (in the parameter I've named `acc`). The initial value of the accumulator is passed as the second argument to `reduce`.

So, at the end, `days` consists of the days of the week where the `frequencyArray` contains a 1.

Then you just call the `join` method on the result, with " and " as the delimiter.

Note that I've used ES2015 syntax, which should work fine with TypeScript you're likely using for Angular 2.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Your frequency array is not an array, it's just 1 number.

```
@Component

weekDays: string[] = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

frequencyArray: number[] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

loadFrequencyLabel() {
  var binary = this.prescription.frequencyArray;
  var label: string;

  for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) { 
     binary[i] = this.weekDays[i];
     return label;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes @woodsprite, you're right, I edited the code, but the problem remains.. I'm sure that it's my fault because I don't understand how can I do